# Java mapper for copying fields from A to B

Tags: java, spring

I have object A, B and they extend object C that has 100 common fields.
I would like to create a mapper, without manually rewriting those 100 fields, is it possible with some spring mechanism ? And instead of `public A mapMe(B)` i would like to have `public void mapMe(B, A)`, or generally `public void mapMe(source, target)` so that this mapper would not create new A object, i want to pass existing A and B objects to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.

Given:

```
    public class ObjectA extends ObjectC {
    }

    public class ObjectB extends ObjectC {
    }

    public class ObjectC {

        private String field1;
        private String field2;

    ...getters, setters
    }
```

You'd use it like this:

```
    ObjectB objectB = new ObjectB();
    objectB.setField1("bField1");

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);

    ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA();
    objectA.setField2("aField2");

    modelMapper.map(objectB, objectA);
    System.out.println(objectA.getField1() + " - " + objectA.getField2());
```

Result: bField1 - aField2

You can change the configuration the way you want, I wasn't sure if I understood your question completely. I'm assuming you want to map values to already existing object A, while skipping null values?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Mapstruct](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct). It creates a mapper between your objects.